# cast timestamp to string having null values also in azure datafactory

Tags: sql, date, azure-data-factory, databricks, azure-databricks

I was trying cast timestamp datatype to string data type. I am having NULL values also in column. I am using to_char function to cast timestamp. But I was doing joining on that column later. While joining it was always getting false. How can cast timestamp so that nothing is effected.

Note: I am cast while loading data from on-prem to azure using ADF.

Below is the sample code.

```
select cast(mbid as varchar(10)) as mbid,TO_CHAR(efdt,'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss') as efdt,TO_CHAR(exdt,'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss') as exdt,cast(facet_id as varchar(10)) as facet_acct_id,
cast(meme_ck as varchar(10)) as meme_ck,cast(poli as varchar(20)) as poli,TO_CHAR(AUDIT_UPDT_DT, 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss') as AUDIT_UPDT_DT,
TO_CHAR(cdc_ts,'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss') as cdc_ts from (
select
mbr_id,
case when eff_dt <= '01-JAN-1970 12:00:00 AM' then to_timestamp('01-JAN-1970 12:00:00 AM') else eff_dt end as eff_dt,
case when exp_dt >= '01-JAN-2099 12:00:00 AM' then null else exp_dt end as exp_dt,facet_acct_id,
meme_ck,
case when length(trim(poli)) = 0 then null when length(trim(poli)) > 15 then upper(trim(substr(trim(poli), 1, 15))) when length(trim(poli)) < 9 then upper(lpad(trim(poli), 9, '0')) else upper(trim(poli)) end as poli,
audit_updt_dt,
cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP at time zone 'GMT' as timestamp) as cdts
from
hsr.MBRHIST) a;
```

Comment: but why are you converting timestamps to strings & then compare them?

Comment: I am having nulls in one of the column so I am comparing in string

Comment: use functions like `nvl` to convert nulls into default values, or something like that